# How to close all running scripts, and restart them later?

Tags: autohotkey

In order to update AutoHotkey, all running scripts must be closed. AutoHotkey processes can be killed with a simple script (see below), but I don't know how to restart the same ones at will. Currently I restart my computer after updating (to launch the AHK scripts in Windows startup folder).

Windows apparently doesn't allow launching multiple files simultaneously. Because I have dozens of AutoHotkey scripts enabled starting them manually isn't feasible.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

Loop
{
#Singleinstance force
Process, Close, Autohotkey.exe
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
; FileDelete, %A_Desktop%\my running scripts.ini

; Get a list of all running AHK scripts:
DetectHiddenWindows, ON
WinGet, id, list, ahk_class AutoHotkey 
Loop, %id% ; retrieves the  ID of the specified windows, one at a time
{
    this_ID := id%A_Index%
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %this_ID%    
    SkriptPath := RegExReplace(title, " - AutoHotkey v" A_AhkVersion )
    If InStr(SkriptPath, A_ScriptFullPath)
        continue
    ; Store the path of each running script in an INI-file and terminate it:
    IniWrite, %SkriptPath%`n, %A_Desktop%\my running scripts.ini, my_running_scripts
    WinClose, %SkriptPath% ahk_class AutoHotkey 
}
; Run %A_Desktop%\my running scripts.ini

; Create a new script in the startup folder that starts the same scripts after rebooting:
FileAppend, 
(
    IniRead, my_running_scripts, `%A_Desktop`%\my running scripts.ini, my_running_scripts
    Loop, parse, my_running_scripts, ``n
        Run `%A_LoopField`%
    ; FileDelete, `%A_ScriptFullPath`%
    ExitApp
)
, %A_Startup%\my running scripts.ahk
ExitApp
return
```

Replace `%A_Startup%` with `%A_Desktop%` if you want to restart the  scripts manually from your desktop.